# Clang pragma specification to enable anonymous structs in clang while compiling C

Tags: c, clang

What pragmas should I use to enable anonymous structs for one struct in clang? In gcc, I'd do something like the following. What's the equivalent in clang?

```
typedef struct _fubar {
    int barfu1;
    int barfu2;
    int barfu3;
} t_fubar;

#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize "-fms-extensions"
typedef struct _fubar_ext {
    struct _fubar; // All contents of _fubar above.
    int barfu4;
} t_fubar_ext;
#pragma GCC pop_options
```